# spring jdbctemplate queryforlist is too slow, how to fix this?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jdbctemplate

When I retrieve a list of data from an oracle database in java by jdbctemplate.queryForList, it is too slow.
The execution of the query on the database takes 1.5 seconds.
To retrieve it in the java, it takes 20 sec.

My application is in java 8 spring boot 2.0.1 and I use jdbctemplate.

The code below :

### application.properties (database properties connection)

```
toto.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:toto
toto.username=toto
toto.password=toto
driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

### DataSourceConfig

```
package com.bnp.paribas.ism.config;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SingleConnectionDataSource;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Autowired
    private DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties;


    @Bean(name = "toto")
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        SingleConnectionDataSource singleConnectionDataSource = new SingleConnectionDataSource();
        singleConnectionDataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getProperty("driver-class-name"));
        singleConnectionDataSource.setUrl(environment.getProperty("toto.url"));
        singleConnectionDataSource.setUsername(environment.getProperty("toto.username"));
        singleConnectionDataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty("toto.password"));
        return singleConnectionDataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name = "totoJdbcTemplate")
    @Autowired
    public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("toto") DataSource toto) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(toto);
    }

}
```

### DAO

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.List;

@Repository
public class TotoDAO {


    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }



    public List<String> getPckSpecificationContent(String schema, String namePck){
        StringBuilder requete = new StringBuilder();
        requete.append("SELECT TEXT ")
                .append("FROM ALL_SOURCE ")
                .append("WHERE OWNER='").append(schema).append("' ")
                .append("AND TYPE='PACKAGE' ")
                .append("AND NAME='").append(namePck).append("'");

        return jdbcTemplate.queryForList(requete.toString(), String.class);
    }

    public List<String> getPckBodyContent(String schema, String namePck){
        StringBuilder requete = new StringBuilder();
        requete.append("SELECT TEXT ")
                .append("FROM ALL_SOURCE ")
                .append("WHERE OWNER=?" )
                .append("AND TYPE=? " )
                .append("AND NAME=?");

        return jdbcTemplate.queryForList(requete.toString(), String.class, schema, "PACKAGE BODY", namePck);
    }

    public List<String> getListPckName(String schema){
        StringBuilder requete = new StringBuilder();
        requete.append("SELECT DISTINCT NAME ")
                .append("FROM ALL_SOURCE ")
                .append("WHERE OWNER='").append(schema).append("' ")
                .append("AND TYPE='PACKAGE' ")
                .append("ORDER BY NAME ASC");

        return jdbcTemplate.queryForList(requete.toString(), String.class);
    }

}
```

### Code test

```
    @Test
    public void test4(){

        long debut = System.nanoTime();

        totoDAO.getPckBodyContent(Constant.SCHEMA_NAME, PCK_NAME);

        logger.info("temps écoulé : {} ", Double.valueOf(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(System.nanoTime() 
         - debut))/1000.0);

    }
```

This query takes 20 seconds to complete.
Should I use something other than querylist?
Something other than jdbctemplate?

Comment: The query doesn't take 20 seconds, mapping all the rows to java objects and obtaining the data takes 18 seconds. You are comparing apples and oranges. I would also suggest to use the Spring Boot provide datasource and JdbcTemplate instead of configuring your own, and set a larger `fetchSize` (the default is 10 leading to a lot of roundtrips if you have many rows).

Comment: set fetch size solve my problem. From 20 sec to 2:). Indeed I get more than 4000 lines. Thanks very much. I come back to the configuration of spring boot provided, I had changed to use singledatasourceconnection suggested by another post.